# Material-ui , remove paper border

Tags: css, material-ui

How to remove the top border in material-ui Paper component. I've tried the following but it seems that it does not work.

```
     <Paper
        sx={{
          border: 0,
          borderTop: 0,
          borderRadius: 0,
        }}
      >
        <Box className="main">
          <Typography variant="h4">O_x</Typography>
          <InvoiceFormCmp />
        </Box>
      </Paper>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUowY.png)

Answer (score 5):

Probably, you haven't noticed that the Paper component is not using any border. You are seeing that line because of the box-shadow CSS property used by the Paper component. You can set it to none with:

```
<Paper sx={{ boxShadow: "none" }}>
  <Box className="main">
    <Typography variant="h4">0_x</Typography>
  </Box>
</Paper>
```

[Check the sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-paper-with-no-boxshadow-kjl31)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Paper sx={{ border: 'none' }}>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).